# Implement the item delete from shopping cart

Tags: android, shopping-cart

I'm trying to implement the item delete from my application cart (I have used this tutorial http://www.androiddom.com/2012/06/android-shopping-cart-tutorial-part-3.html).

When adding an item to cart what I'm doing is sending the item details to cart, `cartActivity` and then I have edit button in the cart in front of each item. Once pressed it it goes to edit screen it loads all the data accordingly. In the `editactivity` I have delete button. What is should I use as reference code? If yes how can I get that code? 
Each item added has a product number as shown in the below screen shot.

[image]

I have used the    `ShoppingCartHelper.java`

```
public class ShoppingCartHelper {

    private static Map<Product, ShoppingCartEntry> cartMap = new HashMap<Product, ShoppingCartEntry>();

    public static void setQuantity(Product product, int quantity) {
        // Get the current cart entry
        ShoppingCartEntry curEntry = cartMap.get(product);

        // If the quantity is zero or less, remove the products
        if (quantity <= 0) {
            if (curEntry != null)
                removeProduct(product);
            return;
        }

        // If a current cart entry doesn't exist, create one
        if (curEntry == null) {
            curEntry = new ShoppingCartEntry(product, quantity);
            cartMap.put(product, curEntry);
            return;
        }

        // Update the quantity
        curEntry.setQuantity(quantity);
    }

    public static int getProductQuantity(Product product) {
        // Get the current cart entry
        ShoppingCartEntry curEntry = cartMap.get(product);

        if (curEntry != null)
            return curEntry.getQuantity();

        return 0;
    }

    public static void removeProduct(Product product) {
        cartMap.remove(product);
    }

    public static List<Product> getCartList() {
        List<Product> cartList = new Vector<Product>(cartMap.keySet().size());
        for (Product p : cartMap.keySet()) {
            cartList.add(p);
        }

        return cartList;
    }

}
```

inside the `editactivity.java`

```
deleteCartButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                ShoppingCartHelper.removeProduct(product); //how can I get the product here, it says to define it


            }
        });
```

Comment: Where is actually problem?

Comment: I have no idea how to implement the delete option, I'm trying to find the way to get some id to my edit screen so i can make sure I have loaded the same item to editactivity from cart activity.

Comment: Just remove it from cartMap (I'm expectiong you're using Map to store cart content) and refresh your UI.

Comment: I have updated the question with my ShoppingCartHelper.java, do you mind telling me what sort of a code should come inside delete button. I have used product but how can I get the select item exactly there

Answer (score 0):

If you're facing problem with passing item's `id` from `CartActivity` to `EditActivity`, you can use `Intent` extras:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("id", product.id); // id must be long
startActivity(intent);
```

`EditActivity.java`:

```
Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    long id = getIntent().getLongExtra("id", 0);
    ...
}
```

If you cannot obtain `ShoppingCartEntry` instance, but you have `Product` instance, you can add following method to `ShoppingCartHelper.java`:

```
public ShoppingCartEntry getByProduct(Product product) {
    return cartMap.get(product);
}
```

Comment: I have added the getByProduct to ShoppingCartHelper.java, what should I do next in cartActivity?

Comment: You can just call `ShoppingCartHelper.removeProduct(product)`

Comment: product inside the bracket is null, how can I assign the selected item to the product

Comment: How do you know, what you want to delete? You have to get product instance by some kind of `id`.

Comment: it means i need to send product instance to edit screen from cart ryt?

Comment: bw it doesn't allow me to get the value of intent.putExtra("id", product.id);